# variable defined in C file is undefined in Assembly file

Tags: c, assembly, linker, operating-system

I'm trying to write a small operating system kernel, and I'm stuck on the PIT. I have defined the variable `CountDown` in my main C file:

```c
...
#include "include/time.h"

volatile unsigned int CountDown = 2;
// also used: extern volatile unsigned int CountDown = 2;

void keyboard_handler()
...
```

and I want to reference it in an assembly file (x86)

```
...
extern keyboard_handler

TimerIRQ:
   push eax
   mov eax, [CountDown]
   test eax, eax
   jz TimerDone
   dec eax
   mov [CountDown], eax

TimerDone:
   pop eax
   iretd
...
```

But when trying to compile, I get the error(s)

```
kernel.asm:21: error: symbol `CountDown' not defined
kernel.asm:25: error: symbol `CountDown' not defined
```

I compile and load the system using the following commands:

```
nasm -f elf32 kernel.asm -o ./build/kasm.o
gcc -m32 -c kernel.c -o ./build/kc.o -fno-stack-protector
ld -m elf_i386 -T ./build/link.ld -o ./kernel ./build/kasm.o ./build/kc.o

echo "Compiled, Loading pc-i440fx-3.1 machine..."
qemu-system-i386 -kernel ./kernel -machine type=pc-i440fx-3.1
```

When compiled, CountDown is referenced in assembly as:

```
    .globl  CountDown
    .data
    .align 4
    .type   CountDown, @object
    .size   CountDown, 4
CountDown:
    .long   2
```

For reference, am trying to implement something like the code shown in this wiki page:
[OSDev Wiki - Programmable Interval Timer](https://wiki.osdev.org/Programmable_Interval_Timer)

I'm not sure if I'm forgetting something or if I lack the experience needed for this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need an `extern CountDown`. Strange you have done that for `keyboard_handler` but not for `CountDown`.

Comment: I completely overlooked that. thank you!